# Как подключить аудио передней панели

Tags: аудио, материнская-плата

Как подключить разъёмы аудиовыходов фронтальной панели (на фото) их к материнской плате (тоже на фото)?

У зелёного разъёма и у розового разъёма - слишком узкие пины (близкорасположенные относительно соседних пинов) и поэтому не хотят спокойно вставать на те, что на материнской плате. В отличии от синего разъёма, который имеет более широкое расстояние между пинами и может быть подключён к материнской плате (но я его не использую). Можно было бы предположить, что просто они не подходят к данной материнской плате, но прошлый пользователь данного системного блока утверждает, что работали аудиовыходы передней панели, и микрофон и наушники. Что делать?

**Материнская плата, вендор и модель**[image: Материнская плата, вендор и модель]

**Материнская плата - пины с левой стороны**[image: Материнская плата - пины с левой стороны]

**Материнская плата - пины с правой стороны**[image: Материнская плата - пины с правой стороны]

**Общий вид аудио-блока фронтальной панели**[image: Общий вид аудио-блока фронтальной панели]

**Разъём зелёного аудиовыхода - для наушников**[image: Разъём зелёного аудиовыхода - для наушников]

**Разъём розового аудиовыхода - для микрофона**[image: Разъём розового аудиовыхода - для микрофона]

**Разъём синего аудиовыхода - не использовал его никогда и вряд ли использовать**[image: Разъём синего аудиовыхода - не использовал его никогда и вряд ли использовать]

---

Не вижу описание к приложенным фотографиям ...

1. белый разъём на 5 пинов - зелёный аудивыход
2. синий разъём на 3 пина - розовый аудиовыход
3. белый разъём на 4 пина (с бОльшими отступами между ними) - синий аудиовыход